# JQuery Validate Dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, validation, drop-down-menu, jquery-validate

I'm using the validation plugin from [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). I'm trying force the user to select an option in the drop down list so here's my html for the list:

```
Select the best option<br/>
<select name="dd1" id="dd1">
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="o1">option 1</option>
<option value="o2">option 2</option>
<option value="o3">option 3</option>
</select> <br/><br/>​
```

And here's the the jquery validation stuff:

```
$("#everything").validate({
    onsubmit: true,
    rules: {
     dd1: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
            return $("#dd1").val() == "none";
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
     dd1: {
      required: "Please select an option from the list, if none are appropriate please select 'Other'",
     },
    }
});
```

I don't see any problems but even when the i select none from the drop down list and click submit, it won't validate it and so doesn't show any messages. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any javascript error in the console ? May not be the problem but strip useless commas like after "dd1" in "messages"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback) for `required()` states:

> To force a user to select an option from a select box, provide an empty options like `<option value="">Choose...</option>`

By having `value="none"` in your `<option>` tag, you are preventing the validation call from ever being made.  You can also remove your custom validation rule, simplifying your code.  Here's a jsFiddle showing it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3v5/

If you can't change the `value` attribute to the empty string, I don't know what to tell you...I couldn't find any way to get it to validate otherwise.

Comment: more than a year later, still helpful, that is beauty of SO... thanks. :-)

Answer (score 8):

As we know jQuery validate plugin invalidates Select field when it has blank value. Why don't we set its value to blank when required.

Yes, you can validate select field with some **predefined value**.

```
$("#everything").validate({
    rules: {
        select_field:{
            required: {
                depends: function(element){
                    if('none' == $('#select_field').val()){
                        //Set predefined value to blank.
                        $('#select_field').val('');
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

We can set blank value for select field but in some case we can't. For Ex: using a function that generates Dropdown field for you and you don't have control over it.

I hope it helps as it helps me.

Answer (score 3):

This was my solution:

I added **required** to the select tag:

```
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select class="form-control" name="HoursEntry" id="HoursEntry" required>
                    <option value="">Select.....</option>
                    <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
                    <option value="0.5">0.50</option>
                    <option value="1">1.00</option>
                    <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
                    <option value="1.5">1.50</option>
                    <option value="2">2.00</option>
                    <option value="2.25">2.25</option>
                    <option value="2.5">2.50</option>
                    <option value="3">3.00</option>
                    <option value="3.25">3.25</option>
                    <option value="3.5">3.50</option>
                    <option value="4">4.00</option>
                    <option value="4.25">4.25</option>
                    <option value="4.5">4.50</option>
                    <option value="5">5.00</option>
                    <option value="5.25">5.25</option>
                    <option value="5.5">5.50</option>
                    <option value="6">6.00</option>
                    <option value="6.25">6.25</option>
                    <option value="6.5">6.50</option>
                    <option value="7">7.00</option>
                    <option value="7.25">7.25</option>
                    <option value="7.5">7.50</option>
                    <option value="8">8.00</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to get it done is by adding `required` into your `select`

```
Select the best option
<br/>

<select name="dd1" id="dd1" required>
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="o1">option 1</option>
<option value="o2">option 2</option>
<option value="o3">option 3</option>
</select> 

<br/><br/>​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#HoursEntry").change(function(){
var HoursEntry = $(#HoursEntry option:selected).val();
if(HoursEntry == "")
{
$("#HoursEntry").html("Please select");
return false;
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="msg"></div>
<!-- put above tag on body to see selected value or error -->
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#HoursEntry").change(function(){
            var HoursEntry = $("#HoursEntry option:selected").val();
            console.log(HoursEntry);
            if(HoursEntry == "")
            {
                $("#msg").html("Please select at least One option");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $("#msg").html("selected val is  "+HoursEntry);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your code a little. Here's a working version (for me):

```
    <select name="dd1" id="dd1">
       <option value="none">None</option>
       <option value="o1">option 1</option>
       <option value="o2">option 2</option>
       <option value="o3">option 3</option>
    </select>  
    <div style="color:red;" id="msg_id"></div>

<script>
    $('#everything').submit(function(e){ 
        var department = $("#msg_id");
        var msg = "Please select Department";
            if ($('#dd1').val() == "") {
                department.append(msg);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
 </script>
```