# validate dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, html-select

I created **dropdown** and i want to validate this.. I am struggling with doing drop down validation.

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <% if (ViewData["Country"] != null) { %>
                <%: Html.DropDownList("Country", "Any")%>
            <%} else { %>
                <select id="Country" name="Country"></select>
            <%} %>

            <% if (ViewData["State"] != null) { %>
                <%: Html.DropDownList("State", "Any")%>
            <%} else { %>
                <select id="State" name="State"></select>
            <%} %>

            <% if (ViewData["City"] != null) { %>
                <%: Html.DropDownList("City", "Any")%>
            <%} else { %>
                <select id="City" name="City"></select>
            <% } %>

            <% if (ViewData["Region"] != null) { %>
                <%: Html.DropDownList("Region", "Any")%>
            <% } else { %>
                <select id="Region" name="Region"></select>
            <% } %>
       </div>
```

This is my drop down box code.. How to validate in jquery?

Comment: What type of validation(s) are you gonna apply?

Comment: @Duk, hey,  you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467682/jquery-validate-dropdown-list

Comment: They all look like they can be null, what are you going to check. If you use strongly typed models you can enable client side validation and use data annotations to describe validation checkout this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

Comment: @n-p-subedi required field validation..

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless your question is about this particular plugin.  It's consider "tag-spam".  Edited.  Thanks.  Also, please at least show an attempt at solving this, rather than simply asking for code.

Answer (score 0):

Assign common class to all select boxes, and then through that common class get the active ids and validate them. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery is probably the best way to validate HTML Controls.

JS:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            if ($("#ddlView :selected").val() == 0) {
                alert("Please select a Course");
            }
            else {
                alert("Success !! You have selected Course : " + $("#ddlView :selected").text()); ;
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<select id="ddlView">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Java Script</option>
        <option value="2">CSS</option>
        <option value="3">JQuery</option>
        <option value="3">HTML</option>
        <option value="3">C#</option>
    </select>

<input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
```