# How to make user to choose an option of dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467682/jquery-validate-dropdown-list) to implement a required dropdown box. The only difference is that the code of dropdown box in my application is in a new page which will be popped up.

The problem is that once user select any option including the one with none value, the form gets submitted!

**Page 1**

```
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate
                                                         /1.9/jquery.validate.js"
                                                        </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

          $("#everything").validate({
              messages: {
                  dd1: {
                     required: "Please select an option from the list, if 
                                none are appropriate please select 'Other'"
                }
            }
          });
          function popup(){
             document.getElementById("mydropbox").style.display = "Block";
              >> send request to server to show the Page 2 in body of mydropbox <<
             return false;
          }
   </script>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="" OnClick="return popup()">popup</a>

    <div id="mydropbox"></div>
...  
</body>
</html>
```

**page 2**

```
<html>
 <body>
    <form id="everything">
             <label for="dd1">Select the best option</label><br/>
             <select name="dd1" id="dd1" class="required">
                 <option value="">None</option>
                 <option value="o1">option 1</option>
                 <option value="o2">option 2</option>
                 <option value="o3">option 3</option>
             </select> 
             <br/><br/>
             <input type="submit" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`required` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/select.html#select.attrs.required) to your [`select`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/select.html#select) element. That should work in modern browsers at least.

It alerts the user if the option they are selecting has an empty value (like the option "None" in your case). You would have do do server-side validation too of course, because you can't rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TtPx9/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="sbt" /> //added id to the submit button sbt
```

**js**

```
$('#sbt').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form submit
    if ($('#dd1 option:selected').text() != 'None') {
        $('#everything').trigger('submit'); // if selected text not = to None then trigger form submit.
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtPx9/)

Remove the submit button from the form and use this

form will be submitted only if the dropdownlist value is changed

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: then if user choose the option with none value even it will get submitted.

Comment: @TimNorman no `none` value is `default` as it is at the `top`. `onchange` event will fire if the user choose other value than `none` and form will be submitted if value is changed from `none` to any other value. also check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/TtPx9/

Comment: THanks, but I need them to click on submit button to submit the form

Comment: @TimNorman added updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TtPx9/1/ now code working on submit button