# how to validate drop down box using jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using below code for validation of fields of my Dialog Box but if I have `select`-box then how we can validate it using same way as they have used for other text input fields ?

Link to access code from Jquery-UI site

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

In the same way I want to validate my `select`-box too.

Comment: show me what  you tried ?

Comment: what do you want to validate ? What should the rules be ? Any Example to show us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check length of selected options and dropdown's `value`, but this is nasty stuff and there are other ways to do it better and more elegant.

Example:

```
var $yourDropdown= $('#dropdownElement');
var $options= $('#dropdownElement option:selected');
if ($options.length == 0 || yourDropdown.val() == "")
{
}
```

More examples [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467682/jquery-validate-dropdown-list), using `jQuery Validate`